# jQuery CSS Animate not working in Firefox, Chrome but working in Safari

Tags: jquery, html, css, jquery-animate

I did some project some time back. One fine day, I relook that project and found that the jquery CSS Animation is not working at all!

Go to the site http://goo.gl/3ZhJEI 
1) Click on Portfolio. 
2) When u click on any of the boxes on Portfolio page, it should fade out and fade in something.

It works a couple of months ago. I'm not sure why it doesn't work now. And the weird part is it works on all browsers locally. And it works on Safari online but not on Firefox and Chrome online. This is extremely weird.

I do not use any CSS3 transistions, all are based on jquery CSS Animate. I've use a require-jquery.js to load the jquery.

Misc Information 
Tested on Firefox 26.0, Chrome Version 32.0.1700.77, Safari 6.1

Comment: Seems to be working fine for me on Chrome and FF

Comment: Hi, at the Portfolio page, when you click one of the boxes, it fades out, and then something should fade in. Do you get something faded in? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I just have problems on SRware Iron version 28. For other browsers it works well.
Maybe you have a good reason not to use CSS animations there, but it is the easiest way to make it works well and without bugs, for example :

```
a img {
opacity: 1;
transition: opacity 1s;
-webkit-transition: opacity 1s;
-moz-transition: opacity 1s;
-o-transition: opacity 1s;
}

a img:hover
{
opacity :0.5;
}
```

Comment: weird. am i the only one having the problems? I can't use hover because it has to be onclick, therefore I need to use js sadly :(

Comment: Oh sorry that was about clicking x) ! But I can tell you that hover does not work well on Iron but the Onclick seems to be fine.